# Ubuntu 15.10 mini iso preseed not reccognized

Tags: ubuntu, preseed

I downloaded an Ubuntu mini iso from the Ubuntu website and want to do a fully automated install. I created a preseed file([preseed](http://hastebin.com/royohoxixa.vbs))

I created an image with this file in the iso.

When i try to start it with the following contents in the txt.cfg. It asks me all questions and nothing seems to be picked up from the preseed file. This is regarding Ubuntu 15.10

I tried to provide the arguments in different orders and adapting the preseed file. Also tried an Ubuntu server image and it also does not work.

`default install
label install
    menu label ^Install
    menu default
    kernel linux
    append file=/cdrom/pre.seed priotity=critical locale=en_US console-setup/layoutcode=us vga=788 initrd=initrd.gz quiet ---`

Edit: Someone added an answer and quickly removed it.  It stated that preseed needs to be in front of "file=". I tried this and the same thing happens. It will not use the preseed file.

Edit : The versions of the txt.cfg i tried so far : [txt.cfg](http://hastebin.com/haquzuzuru.mel)

Comment: Can you have mounted it on /cdrom while working, but at the end of the day when booting it is /pre.seed and not /cdrom/pre.seed?

Comment: I edited the command in the menu with ```append preseed/file=/pre.seed ``` and with ```append file=/pre.seed ```. Both did not work. It asked me all questions again at installation.

Comment: Please show use the first 13 lines of your preseed file and an ls -la of pre.seed

Comment: Actually it was me. I use a preseed but from a URL. In Debian instructions it says: if you're booting a remastered CD: preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg

Comment: There is a link to it in the question : http://hastebin.com/royohoxixa.vbs

Comment: have a look at the las comment about Debian and the ls -la.

Comment: (I do not do it over a CD, i do it via TFTP / PXE)

Comment: I am sorry, but i do not understand. Do you mean in the preseed file? If so which line ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31770/discussion-between-dany-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Comment: chat not working for me?

Comment: oddly enough, I can see your comments in chat, but I do not have a box to answer

Comment: Okay. Strange,  but what did you mean by your comment  " have a look at the las comment about Debian and the ls -la. – Rui F Ribeiro 7 mins ago "

Comment: one last idea, mount the iso either in CD or the image and double check the files (I guess you already did it, but even then...)

Comment: I ended up creating a completely new preseed file with spaces between d-i and the rest of the string in stead of four spaces/tabs. Downloaded a fresh image from the ubuntu website and started anew.. Also created a new txt.cfg file.This also did not work. Now i am on Ubuntu IRC to see if someone can help :)

Comment: Mine has only one space.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : The manual is tucked away here -> https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apbs01.html#preseed-methods This tells there will be no preseeding froma file with a mini iso from ubuntu. This is not specified in any other documentation on the ubuntu site and it is nowhere referenced in other guides that i have seen.

Comment: bummer. I could swear I am using it from netinstall actually, and place it int TFTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result of 30 hours of frustration:

- Ubuntu mini ISO cannot preseed from a file inside an ISO
- Debian netinstall ISO can preseed from a file in the ISO
- Ubuntu and debian Netinstalls cannot retrieve preseed files over SSL

Now i created a public available web server and load the preseed file from there. Why the Ubuntu cannot use a preseed file from in the ISO is a mystery to me, but there must be a valid reason.

I have (ab)used https://rawgit.com/ via github secret gist for hosting preseed files. You can use the cdn url without https. Just remove the s and you're good to go.

Comment: Interesting that tidbit about ssl. It took me hours too to get it, but I did not even remember now. So same in Debian. My mistake is that I am using a netinstall too. You can add to the bulllet points the errors are not very helpful. I was not more helpful than that just because I did it 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is my isolinux.cfg file:

```
menu hshift 13
menu width 49
menu margin 8


menu title Installer boot menu
DEFAULT AutoInstaller
LABEL AutoInstaller
    menu label ^AutoInstaller
    kernel /install/vmlinuz
    append initrd=/install/initrd.gz locale=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us hostname=unassigned preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed/preseed.seed
```

It works perfectly for me. I am using Ubuntu server15.10.